# Cloud values are not loaded

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My code snippet in order to build a point cloud as below:

```
static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LD2.pose.position.x, pose3D_LD2.pose.position.y, pose3D_LD2.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.x, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.y, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.z, previous_poseLD_.pose.orientation.w));
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time(pose3D_LD2.header.stamp), "base_link", "laser"));
tfListener_.waitForTransform("base_link", "laser", previous_scan_.header.stamp, ros::Duration(2.0));
projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("base_link", previous_scan_, cloud, tfListener_);
```

It neither gives error and nor emits warning messages. However, when I run "rostopic echo /cloud" it gives the following information:

```
header: 
  seq: 198
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: cloud
points: []
channels: []
---
header: 
  seq: 199
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: cloud
points: []
channels: []
---
header: 
  seq: 200
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: cloud
points: []
channels: []
---
header: 
  seq: 201
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: cloud
points: []
channels: []
---
```

It seems that the point cloud is not successfully configured. Apparently, when running the rviz, it complaints that "no messages received".

Any remedy for this weird behavior?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12748/cloud-values-are-not-loaded/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
It's just solved! Thanks anyway.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-25**:
Does the incoming LaserScan have any messages coming in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution can be referred [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/3714/not-being-able-to-lookup-transform-leading-to).

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code looks good as far as I can see. Are you sure that previous_scan_ is actually filled with points? I would add two debugging statements at the end of your code snippet to check if the number of points in the laser scan and the number of points in the point cloud actually differ:

```
ROS_DEBUG("Laser scan: %lu", (unsigned long)previous_scan_.ranges.size());
ROS_DEBUG("Point cloud: %lu", (unsigned long)cloud.points.size());
```

Note that your node needs to have the log level set to debug to print the output. If you feel lazy, you can also use `ROS_INFO` which should be displayed per default.

If you have something greater than zero in the scan but zero points in the cloud then something is probably wrong with your laser scan's metadata, maybe range_min or range_max.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
Thanks anyway..

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-25**:
There is also a config file. See here for more information on that: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-25**:
It's just solved! Thanks anyway. I'm just curios about "Note that your node needs to have the log level set to debug..", how do I do this normally? Is it just tick log option in the rxconsole, or is there another way of doing it?